# 500 Internal Server Error - ActionView::Template::Error in Rails Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting 500 Internal server error on my production rails site and this is what I am seeing it on logs/production.log. Surprisingly the code works on local server in development

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11745ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  (in /home/jason/public_html/site/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
    8:     
    9:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    10: 
    11:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    12:  
    13:   </head>
    14:   <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__243082314235891573_4889460'
  app/controllers/main_controller.rb:18:in `index'
```

I am little lost here, any help ?

Here is the Application.css

```
 /* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

/* Main Body */

body {
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to precompile assets when push to production

Comment: @Jun1st- How to precompile assets in production ?

Comment: bundle exec rake assets:precompile. you should put "How to precompile ... " into the google search box instead of asking here:)

Comment: @Jun1st - btw, in config/environments/production.rb, it is "config.assets.compile = true"

Comment: @Jun1st - I ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile, but got this error "rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  (in /home/jason/public_html/mysite/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
", so basically the same error as above.

Comment: Please attach application.css in the question.

Comment: @ecleel - application.css attached, though I don't think there is anything wrong with it as it has nothing much in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to precompile assets when push to production

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

also, read [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) doc some, worth your time

Comment: I ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile, but got this error "rake aborted! undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (in /home/jason/public_html/mysite/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css) ", so basically the same error as above.

Comment: finally I got it solved, thanks, I certainly have to go through asset pipeline to fully understand it

Comment: btw, when I am keeping "config.assets.compile = false", I am  getting 500 internal server error which is surprising since I am doing rake asset:precompile, any idea ? since i certainly don't want to keep config.assets.compile as true which is causing lot of memory usage

Comment: sorry my mistake, the production database was empty! I have filled it and now everything is fine. One last question, should I keep config.assets.compile = false or config.assets.compile = true ? thanks

Comment: in production, you should set it to false, and precompile assets when you push to prod

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately when I keep it as FALSE, I am getting same 500 Internal server error. It is being caused by a xxxxxxx.css file in assets/stylesheets folder as I think rails only want .scss files, how to fix this ? I thought we are allowed to have .css files in stylesheets folder ?

Answer (score 0):

For people like me, who end up here after a similar error, but without a stack trace: the gem `better_errors` provided me with the info to fix the issue.