# 500 Internal Server Error - ActionView::Template::Error in Rails Production second pass

Tags: templates, undefined, gitlab

Loved the previous question at:
 [500 Internal Server Error - ActionView::Template::Error in Rails Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596141/500-internal-server-error-actionviewtemplateerror-in-rails-production)

I get the same error when browsing the git tree via the web (internal 500), but the answer there said I should run

```
 bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and referred me to
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

I am running GitLab 7.6.1 0286222 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS fully up to date.  That allows me to push and pull from local git machines fine and look around via the web service as well.  I ran the revised assets:precompile as suggested below, but the problem continues for me.

So as to my specific error.  In the production log I get:

```
git@git01:~/gitlab/log$ tail -n 20 production.log
Started GET "/chef/cheftest/tree/master/cookbooks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-24 16:03:25 -0500
Processing by Projects::TreeController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"chef/cheftest", "id"=>"master/cookbooks"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 490ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    1: - tree, commit = submodule_links(submodule_item)
    2: %tr{ class: "tree-item" }
    3:   %td.tree-item-file-name
    4:     %i.fa.fa-archive
  app/models/repository.rb:162:in `method_missing'
  app/models/repository.rb:228:in `submodule_url_for'
  app/helpers/submodule_helper.rb:6:in `submodule_links'
  app/views/projects/tree/_submodule_item.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_projects_tree__submodule_item_html_haml___742655240099390426_69818877669240'
  app/helpers/tree_helper.rb:19:in `render_tree'
  app/views/projects/tree/_tree.html.haml:42:in `_app_views_projects_tree__tree_html_haml__47884322835133800_69818822684460'
  app/views/projects/tree/show.html.haml:9:in `_app_views_projects_tree_show_html_haml__1575471590709486656_69818822138660'
  app/controllers/projects/tree_controller.rb:13:in `show'
```

I would be happy to run any commands and edit any configuration files as needed, but please let me know where the files are and how to run the commands.  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo gitlab-rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I stood up a new instances of:
GitLab 7.6.1 0286222 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS fully up to date

Comment: I made a copy of the problem git repo on the new server and got the same error.  Next I ran the gitlab-rake command as suggested and it took quite a while before giving an Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - ....  In that case I just moved the offending file to /tmp and tried again.  Got a little further in the compile before getting another permission error.  In that case I used touch to create an empty file (had been missing) and chmod to grant access.  That did the trick and I can now precompile quickly with no errors.

Comment: The new error block is:
Started GET "/chef/cheftest/tree/master/cookbooks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-31 11:57:57 -0500
Processing by Projects::TreeController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"chef/cheftest", "id"=>"master/cookbooks"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1085ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    1: - tree, commit = submodule_links(submodule_item)
    2: %tr{ class: "tree-item" }
    3:   %td.tree-item-file-name
    4:     %i.fa.fa-archive
  app/models/repository.rb:162:in `method_missing'
...

Comment: The key to this error is the line below the 'method_missing' call.  It has 'submodule_url_for' which refers to git sub-repos which are called submodules.  In particular a user had copied the contents of an external repo into a sub-directory into our shared repo and had included the .git sub-directory.  Git itself was only moderately upset with the incorrect submodule, but gitlab gave the 500 error.  Removing the sub-directory returned from the 'git submodule' command resolved the issue.